# Static arrays inside of functions error C

Tags: c

```
static const int LOG_MAX = 31;
static int log_table[LOG_MAX];
```

This code is inside of a function in C. When I try to compile I get the error:

> "main.c:19:16: error: storage size of 'log_table' isn't constant".

I don't understand this since `LOG_MAX` is `const`.

Just to clarify this is C code and I am using GCC.

Comment: Use a #define instead maybe?

Comment: Which programming language are you asking about? C and C++ are different languages and in this case you will get different answers, depending on which programming language standard version that is used.

Comment: the problem is the declaration of static const, i answered bellow

Comment: @JoãoPinho Unfortunately, your answer was incorrect...

Comment: @Lundin why? it compiles fine

Comment: @JoãoPinho 1. It doesn't answer the question. 2. The order of `const` and `static` does not matter. Actually, what you posted is _worse_ than what the OP had, because your version may become obsolete in a future version of C. See C11 6.11.5 `"The placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature."`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In older C and C++ standards, the array bounds of an array had to be a constant literal evaluated at compile time. A `const` variable isn't necessary evaluated at compile time, it could be created in runtime as a local variable. Also, as pointed out in another answer, `const` should actually be regarded read-only rather than anything else.

In all C and C++ standards, `static` arrays must always have their size set using a constant literal. (Or to be picky, this applies to any variable with *static storage duration*)

In newer C standards (C99, C11) however, the code you posted is perfectly fine if you leave out the `static` keyword. It will then create a variable-length array (VLA), which may or may not be what you wanted to do.

I'm not sure about the latest C++11 standard, but as far as I know it does not support VLAs.

Answer (score 3):

`const` does not mean constant in C but rather read-only. `LOG_MAX` is not a constant in your program.

Here are two ways to have a constant:

```
#define LOG_MAX 31
```

or

```
enum {
    LOG_MAX = 31
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't valid C, even though the `int` is const and static.
I would recommend doing something like

```
#define LOG_MAX 31
static int log_table[LOG_MAX];
```

Comment: @svk variable length arrays with static storage duration are not supported in c99.

Comment: @svk Not for static arrays, it's not valid even in C99.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, didn't notice `static`.

Answer (score 1):

This fails since a `const int` variable is not considered a compile-time constant in C.

But since the array is going to be static, you can be sure that the "full" declaration is always available, i.e. it's never going to be referenced through a pointer. Thus, you can inline the size and use `sizeof` in all places where you wanted to use `LOG_MAX`:

```
static int log_table[32];
```

and then elsewhere in the same function:

```
const size_t log_max = sizeof log_table / sizeof *log_table;
```

This keeps the "magic constant" around, but only in one place and its purpose should be pretty clear given the way the `log_table` is used. This is all inside a single function, after all, it's not scary global data.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the preprocessor :

```
#define LOG_MAX 31
static int log_table[LOG_MAX];
```